# Changing the color of a JButton with click won't work

Tags: java, swing

```
public class LevelEditorButton extends JButton
{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int i;

public int getState()   {return i;}
public void increaseState()
{
    if(i == 2)
        i = 0;
    else
        i++;
    changeState();
}

public LevelEditorButton()
{
    i = 0;
    changeState();
    this.setOpaque(true);
}
public void changeState()
{
    if(i == 0)
        this.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    else if(i == 1)
        this.setBackground(Color.RED);
    else 
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    this.setOpaque(true);
}
}

public class ChangeColorButtonListener extends LevelEditorButton implements ActionListener
{
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
    this.increaseState();
    }

}
```

Programming on my mac always tends to give me weird bugs with JButtons, so I'm kinda lost in where to go from here. When I debug it, it shows that the color of the button has changed but won't show up on the screen. I've tried repaint(), revalidate() and updateUI(). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you never apply your ActionListener to the button. Two solutions for that:

make a constructor and apply here itself as listener

```
ChangeColorButtonListener(){
        this.addActionListener(this);
    }
```

or do it in the calling class like this:

```
ChangeColorButtonListener  ccb = new ChangeColorButtonListener();
ccb.addActionListener(ccb);
```